# Is there any way to get user news through the official Instagram API?

Tags: instagram

I want to build Instagram client for Ubuntu. I already figured out how to get data like user feed through access token through Instagram API. But I can't figure out how to get user news (e.g. someone liked your photo, mentioned you in comment etc.), I guess user need to be logged on to watch his news (via http://instagram.com/api/v1/news/inbox/).

So, the question: is there any way to get user feed through API, or through access token? I don't want to request user password in my application, all I got is access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This endpoint (v1/news/inbox/) is not supported by official Instagram API. By the way; you can't access the data.